# Hiding ContentControl when child is hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, caliburn.micro

I have the following code in a view:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="BottomPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="200" />
```

which is databound to this property in the model

```
public PanelsViewModel BottomPanel
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to hide the ContentControl when its child is hidden (something that does not happen actually.

Is there anyway to do this? PanelViewModel is a ViewModel with an associated UserControl View (which visibility is databound to the count of the items of a tab control).

Thank you.

Comment: how is the child added?

Comment: Using caliburn micro... Dynamically aty runtime.